# API end point output JSON filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have an end point API. There are four objects with keys, `id`, `group`, `name` and `date_modified`. I am using AngularJS 1 to call the API and print the output. Now, there are few multiple entries, where `group` and `name` are same but `date_modified` is different.

To show the output, I want to filter it in a way that `if group and name are same in an object then it will take the object where date_modified value is highest and ignore the others`.

End point API JSON structure :-

```
[
    {

        "id": 1,
        "group": "AB",
        "name": "John",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:01:47Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 2,
        "group": "BC",
        "name": "Alex",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:04:43Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 3,
        "group": "AB",
        "name": "John",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-29T12:00:02Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 4,
        "group": "CD",
        "name": "Peter",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-29T12:00:07Z"

    }
]
```

services.js :-

```
app.factory('Instlistdata', function($resource) {

    var list_data = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/lists/?format=json' ;



    return $resource(list_data, {}, {

      query: {
          method: 'GET',
          isArray:true,
        }

    });


});
```

Controller.js :-

```
app.controller('dasboardController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$window', 'Instlistdata', function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $window, Instlistdata) {


    $scope.lists = []; 

    Instlistdata.query({},function(data) {

    $scope.lists = data;

    console.log(data);

    });

}]);
```

Now, it is giving me the JSON output in console. But I want filtered output, i.e

```
[
    {

        "id": 1,
        "group": "AB",
        "name": "John",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:01:47Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 2,
        "group": "BC",
        "name": "Alex",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:04:43Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 3,
        "group": "CD",
        "name": "Peter",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-29T12:00:07Z"

    }
]
```

`"date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:01:47Z"` is higher that the `"date_modified": "2018-01-29T12:00:02Z"` where `"group" : "AB"` and `"name" : "John"` . You can see we ignored the other one.

Comment: Please clarify you question. You want this to be done with js code (ie angular service or controller) or do you want this implemented via an angular filter?

Comment: js code will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using something like the following code:

```
var array = [
    {

        "id": 1,
        "group": "AB",
        "name": "John",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:01:47Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 2,
        "group": "BC",
        "name": "Alex",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:04:43Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 3,
        "group": "AB",
        "name": "John",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-29T12:00:02Z"

    },
    {

        "id": 4,
        "group": "CD",
        "name": "Peter",
        "date_modified": "2018-01-29T12:00:07Z"

    }
];

function keep(el, subArray) {
  var found = subArray.filter(function(current) {
    return current.id != el.id && current.name == el.name && current.group == el.group;
  });

  if (found && found.length > 0) {
    var keepThis = true
    var date1 = new Date(el.date_modified)
    found.forEach(function(foundEl) {
      var date2 = new Date(foundEl.date_modified)
      keepThis = date1.getTime() > date2.getTime() && el.id < foundEl.id
    })
    return keepThis
  } else {
    return true
  }
}

var filteredArray = array.filter(function(el, index, arr) {
  return keep(el, arr)
})
```

In this snippet if you replace array variable with the fetched data (i.e.: $scope.lists in your controller) you will have the desired output. Keep in mind though that I did not change the id property since this is something that you usually do not change. So my output is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "group": "AB",
    "name": "John",
    "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:01:47Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "group": "BC",
    "name": "Alex",
    "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:04:43Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "group": "CD",
    "name": "Peter",
    "date_modified": "2018-01-29T12:00:07Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: It is actually checking the first two objects only. If there are multiple objects (more than 2) with same group and name, then it ignores the others.

Comment: To check this, add one more object, like {
    "id": 5,
    "group": "AB",
    "name": "John",
    "date_modified": "2018-01-30T12:05:47Z
  } , you can see that it is still printing the object with id 5

Comment: Since we handle timestamps this is case should be rare. I fixed it regardless.